# Comparing an inputted string to multiple strings efficiently

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for on this website. Apologies if it has already been answered in the past!
Essentially, I'm trying to compare a user inputted string to multiple strings pre-established in the program as a "database".

As an example

```java
System.out.println("Enter a name to check the database");
Scanner names= new Scanner(System.in);
String nameinput= names.next();
if(!nameinput.equals( *[ database]?* )
System.out.println("There is no such name, you cannot continue");
```

How do I check if the inputted string is not equal to the entire database individually?

I have the database set up simply as

```java
class database

{String name, name, name, name... etc.}
```

I'm trying to stick to keeping things simple and using the database, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you have a class that contains individual names as fields. It seems like you are looking for a simple collection instead:

```
List<String> database = Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3");
System.out.println("Enter a name to check the database");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.next();
if (database.contains(input)) {
    System.err.println("There is no such name, you cannot continue");
}
```

`Arrays.asList` simply initializes the collection with the 3 items. You can later dynamically add or remove items with `database.add` or `database.remove`.

I suggest reading about [Java collections](https://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java#:%7E:text=The%20Collection%20in%20Java%20is,a%20single%20unit%20of%20objects.) and their usage

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you! I am not very familiar with arrays yet, and I wasn't sure where to look to find a method like [array].contains(). I appreciate your response.

Comment: One very important note! `database` is NOT an array, but an `ArrayList`. I suggest to read about the difference as well :) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: Will do, thank you for the information as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make a list of all the names available in the database. So database class will have a method like
public List getData ()
It will return all the available names. To make the comparison easier, you can try to have the names in the list as uppercase or lowercase using .toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase()

So when you get the input string from user, convert that string to uppercase or lowercase based on your data.
Then simply you can check if this input string is part of list using contains method.

something like,
if(!availableNames.contains(inputName))
System.out.println("There is no such name, you cannot continue");